# Как правильно отфильтровать массив чтобы были только неотрицательные числа

Tags: javascript

```js
function filter_Arr(arr) {
  let filters = arr.filter(number => parseInt(number) >= 0)
  console.log(filters)
  return filters;
}

let arr = [0, 1, "1", 2, '2', -3, 3];

filter_Arr(arr);
```

По моему кодy выводит: `[0, 1, "1", 2, '2', 3]`

хотя вывод должен быть: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

Как правильно отфильтровать массив, чтобы остались только **неотрицательные числа**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function filter_Arr(arr) {  
  return arr.filter(number => typeof number == 'number' && number >= 0);
}

console.log(filter_Arr([0, 1, "1", 2, '2', -3, 3]));
```

Comment: @ΝNL993 не надо самодеятельности

Comment: Странный диалог, конечно :)

Comment: @EzioMercer https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/723535  а так уже не странный?

Comment: Не, я понимал, что это явно не с просто сказано, но я подумал он удалил свой комментарий на котрый вы ответили, а так уже не странный)